# Get specific values from CURL JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

This is the code:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url = "http://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/".$ip;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$info = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $info;
?>
```

I have this output:

```
{ "businessName" : "", "businessWebsite" : "", "city" : "Mountain View", "continent" : "North America", "country" : "United States", "countryCode" : "US", "ipName" : "google-public-dns-a.google.com", "ipType" : "Residential", "isp" : "Google", "lat" : "37.3860", "lon" : "-122.0838", "org" : "Google Inc.", "query" : "8.8.8.8", "region" : "California", "status" : "success" } 1
```

But i need this (only city or any isolated value)

```
Mountain View
```

Comment: $json = json_decode($info, true); echo $json['city'];

Comment: I try use json_decode, but my result is the same. Full info, not just the city. Maybe a server problem with json_decode?

Have another way? Without json_decode?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to decode the JSON and then access the class property:

```
$ipInfo = json_decode($info);
$city = $ipInfo->city;
```

Comment: I try use json_decode, but my result is the same. Full info, not just the city. Maybe a server problem with json_decode?

Have another way? Without json_decode?

Answer (score 1):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
      $json = json_decode($info, true); 
      echo $json['city'];
```

Or:

```
<?php
     $user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
     $geo = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/$user_ip"));
     $country = $geo->country;
     $city = $geo->city;
     $ipType = $geo->ipType;
     $businessName = $geo->businessName;
     $businessWebsite = $geo->businessWebsite;

     echo "Location $city";
?>
```

Comment: I try use json_decode, but my result is the same. Full info, not just the city. Maybe a server problem with json_decode?

Have another way? Without json_decode?

Comment: @ArtaxerxesSaint's try

Comment: he's probably using curl instead of file_get_contents, and he's not using CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with a parameter of `true` to get an array.

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url = "http://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/".$ip;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$info = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$array = json_decode($info, true);
echo $array['city'];
```

Comment: I try use json_decode, but my result is the same. Full info, not just the city. Maybe a server problem with json_decode?

Have another way? Without json_decode?